# Remove parent categories from subcategory in URLs in Magento 1.9.2.3

Tags: magento, url-rewriting, categories

Magento version is 1.9.2.3.

I have tried following solution which doesn't work for me.

Step 1: Go to app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php copy this file to app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php because it is core Magento file so that we have to copy that file into the app/code/local.

Step 2: Now search for the getCategoryRequestPath($category, $parentPath) around line 698 in Magento ver. 1.9.1.0

Step 3: Search if (null === $parentPath) around line 717 and comment the line as below:

```
/* if (null === $parentPath) {
$parentPath = $this->getResource()->getCategoryParentPath($category);
}
elseif ($parentPath == '/'){*/
$parentPath = ''; //DO NOT Comment this line
//}
```

Step 4: Now Go to the Magento admin and Clear Cache System->Cache Management and Reindex System->Index Management the data.

Step 5: Refresh your browser cache and navigate again now you will see only the Sub Category in Url not the Parent Category just like as http://www.abcxyz.com/test-category-level-1-3.html - See more at: http://www.expertwebadvisor.com/remove-parent-category-path-from-sub-category-url-in-magento/#sthash.cy3HvxwW.dpuf

I have also tried this solution which doesn't work for me.

Suppose you want to remove parent category path from url such as Url-> www.domain.com/cat1/cat2 to www.domain.com/cat2

USAGE :

```
Go to the Magento Admin Panel -> System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Seo Options
Select yes or no from "Use Parent Category Path for Category URLs"
Refresh category url index.
```

Option YES => www.domain.com/cat1/cat2

Option NO => www.domain.com/cat2

Help me if you have another solution

Answer (score 1):

Your first alternative needs to work. Check if your override for "Mage_Catalog_Model_Url" is working fine. Try die() within the method.

I have did that for a particular category id. Where I need to remove the category with id '4' from every category URL. And below is code for it:

```
public function getCategoryRequestPath($category, $parentPath)
{
    $storeId = $category->getStoreId();
    $idPath  = $this->generatePath('id', null, $category);
    $suffix  = $this->getCategoryUrlSuffix($storeId);

    if (isset($this->_rewrites[$idPath])) {
        $this->_rewrite = $this->_rewrites[$idPath];
        $existingRequestPath = $this->_rewrites[$idPath]->getRequestPath();
    }

    if ($category->getUrlKey() == '') {
        $urlKey = $this->getCategoryModel()->formatUrlKey($category->getName());
    }
    else {
        $urlKey = $this->getCategoryModel()->formatUrlKey($category->getUrlKey());
    }

    $categoryUrlSuffix = $this->getCategoryUrlSuffix($category->getStoreId());
    if (null === $parentPath && $category->getParentId() != 4) {
        $parentPath = $this->getResource()->getCategoryParentPath($category);
    }
    elseif($category->getParentId() == 4){
        $parentPath = '';
    }
    elseif ($parentPath == '/') {
        $parentPath = '';
    }
    $parentPath = Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrlPath($parentPath,
        true, $category->getStoreId());

    $requestPath = $parentPath . $urlKey . $categoryUrlSuffix;
    if (isset($existingRequestPath) && $existingRequestPath == $requestPath . $suffix) {
        return $existingRequestPath;
    }

    if ($this->_deleteOldTargetPath($requestPath, $idPath, $storeId)) {
        return $requestPath;
    }

    return $this->getUnusedPath($category->getStoreId(), $requestPath,
        $this->generatePath('id', null, $category)
    );
}
```